# How to align imageview, and two text at center of screen android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Hi I have parent layout as LinearLayout and I need to place an imageview at center and after that two textview one after another at center of screen. At bottom of the screen is an icon.

I placed everything but imageview and two textview are not aligning at center of screen. Here is layout.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   //this image and two textview, i need to place at center of screen
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/seat_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/on_logo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_size20"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seat_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/another_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_size10"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_size10"
        android:text="TEst 2"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_size10">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/on_boarding_circle_arrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_arrow" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I really couldn't figure out what mistake I am doing in this design. ImageView, and two text are placing at top of screen and not in center of screen.

Comment: how's the output ur getting? show screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed some dimensions and images, correct those and you are good to go.

try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/seat_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/seat_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test1"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/another_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_size10"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_size10"
                android:text="TEst 2"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_size10">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/on_boarding_circle_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/seat_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seat_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test1"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/Grey"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/another_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="TEst 2"
            android:textAllCaps="false"

            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/on_boarding_circle_arrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/acircle" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that you are using linear layout so it is aligning the layouts one after another.So you need to use relative layout and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   //this image and two textview, i need to place at center of screen
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/seat_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/on_logo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_size20"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seat_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/another_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_size10"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_size10"
        android:text="TEst 2"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_size10">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/on_boarding_circle_arrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_arrow" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RelativeLayout` at the bottom is the problem. And add `android:gravity="center"` to your parent `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Just add android:gravity="center" in your root LinearLayout and remove last RelativeLayout and see

Answer (score 0):

cut the  'layout_gravity' and 'gravity' parameters from child LinearLayout and paste this to Parent LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/seat_icon"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
 Your code....
```

---

```
 >
```